# first Dropdown hide on second drop down click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am using 2 codrops dropdwon menus in single page. I want to close the first drop down menu   when user clicks on the 2nd drop down menu.

I am using below code in my project.

```
<select id="Select1" class="cd-select">
    <option value="-1" selected>Menu 1</option>
    <option value="7" >subMenu1</option>
    <option value="8" >subMenu2</option>
    <option value="9" >subMenu3</option></select>

// 2nd Menu
<select id="Select2" class="cd-select">
    <option value="-1" selected>Menu 2</option>
    <option value="2" >subMenu1</option>
    <option value="5" >subMenu2</option></select>
```

.aspx Page Java Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Select1').dropdown({
            gutter: 5,
            stack: false,
            delay: 100,
            slidingIn: 100
        });
        $('#Select2').dropdown({
            gutter: 5,
            stack: false,
            delay: 100,
            slidingIn: 100
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to close `Select1` when user click on `Select2`. Please give me suggestion how to do this.
Help me.

- **[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/oye7bq5q/)**

Comment: Please do not include the entire codebase of a plugin you are using. We only require the code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
check the answer to this question:
[jquery drop down menu closing by clicking outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463486/jquery-drop-down-menu-closing-by-clicking-outside)

I added it to your fiddle, it works functionally but the dropdowns lose their layout.
You can try calling the hide() function when clicking on the other dropdown, instead of $(document).

Comment: actually I want to close the first dropdown - not to close that dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution - I just put this code inside `document.ready()` function and it works.

```
$('.cd-dropdown').click(function() {
$('.cd-active').not($(this))
        .removeClass('cd-active')
        .children('ul').css('height', 'auto')
        .children('li').css('top', 0);});
```

Thanks