# How to use Javascript to close css drop down menu on outside click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use pure javascript (not jquery) to close a pure css drop-down menu I have created when clicking outside of the menu. How can I do this?

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <div class="submenu">
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu">
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
</ul>
```

That's the basic structure of my HTML. I want to close the submenu if clicking outside of the submenu. Any way to do so with pure javascript? So far I've tried this:

**Javascript:**

```
        <script>
            document.onclick = closeMenu();
            function closeMenu() {
                document.getElementsByClassName("submenu").style.display = 'none';
            }
        </script>
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463486/jquery-drop-down-menu-closing-by-clicking-outside

Comment: The question specifies pure javascript and the duplicate link is an answer using jQuery

Comment: you should just have `document.onclick = closeMenu` however this will still fire when you click on the menu itself since you are observing the whole document you need to exclude your list from the observer.

Comment: How are the menus opened?

Comment: @Shaggy the menus are opened on hover.

Comment: They'll close, then, when you move your cursor off them.

Comment: @Shaggy Yes, but not on a touch screen device. I am doing this to make my site mobile-compatible.

Comment: Still no need for JavaScript. "Click" anywhere else on your page and the `:hover` pseudo class no longer applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few changes: you are assigning the `onclick` incorrectly, it should be a reference to your function, not the result of calling your function:

```
 document.onclick = closeMenu;
```

Second, you need to use event delegation to determine if the clicked element is a descendent of your `submenu` div. Something like this function should work for figuring out if the event target node is a child of submenu:

```
function parentIsSubmenu(child) {
     var node = child.parentNode;
     while (node != null) {
         if ((node.className || '').indexOf('submenu') > -1) {
             return true;
         }
         node = node.parentNode;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Alter your `closeMenu` function to check if the clicked element is a child of submenu, if not, *loop through* each submenu item and set display to none (what you currently have would not work).

```
function closeMenu(event) {
    if(!parentIsSubmenu(event.target)) {
        var submenus = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
        for(var i = 0; i < submenus.length; i++) {
            submenus[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/m2muz5en/

Comment: It works, however after it closes the submenu, upon trying to reopen it it will not open.

Comment: You just need to include your submenu trigger in your event target check like this: https://jsfiddle.net/m2muz5en/1/

Comment: my trigger is the :hover pseudo class in css. How would I implement that as my submenu trigger? Sorry, I'm really new at all this.

Comment: I think you need to post more of your code (including css). If the `:hover` pseudo class is controlling whether or not your menu is displayed, it would follow that not hovering over it would hide it.

Comment: Well the problem is that on touch screen clicking opens the menus but clicking off of them doesn't close them.

Comment: any ideas on how to fix that?