# Drop down menu that closes to click elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

```js
jQuery('.account strong').click(function(e){
  jQuery(this).parent('div').addClass('show');
  jQuery('.account-dropdown').slideToggle(200);
});
```

```css
.account-dropdown{
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px #555;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 46px;
  width: 145px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="account">
  <strong>Your account</strong>
  <div class="account-dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

I want to change my script so when you open it, the menu can be closed anywhere.

For example, if the currently open menu closes only if we click on `".account strong '`.

I want the menu to be closed anywhere from less div `'account-dropdown'`.

You can help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery drop down menu closing by clicking outside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463486/jquery-drop-down-menu-closing-by-clicking-outside)

Comment: Here is an example - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKZBdJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer below code:

```js
$('.account strong').click(function(e) {
  $(this).parent('div').addClass('show');
  $('.account-dropdown').slideToggle(200);
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if ($('.account-dropdown').is(":visible")) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".account-dropdown").length === 0) {
      $('.account-dropdown').slideToggle(200);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.account-dropdown {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px #555;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 46px;
  width: 145px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="account">
  <strong>Your account</strong>
  <div class="account-dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```