# How to close drop-down when clicking anywhere in the page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

Hi i am developing SPA in angularjs. On successful user login i am setting one drop-down in the upper right corner. whenever we click drop-down will expand. I want to close that drop-down whenever user clicks anywhere in the page.

Below is my code to generate dropdown.

```
 var id = document.getElementById('ProfileDropdown');
        id.innerHTML = $scope.ProfileDropdown = '  <div data-drop-down>' + ' <ul>' +
                '<li ><a ui-sref="Dashboard.Userprofile">User Profile</a></li>' +
            '<li><a ui-sref="Dashboard.changepassword">Change Password</a></li>' +
              '<li><a ui-sref="Dashboard.LeaseListings">Lease Request</a></li>' +
                 '<li><a ui-sref="#">Service Request</a></li>' +
                   '<li><a ui-sref="Dashboard.NewServiceRequest">New Service Request</a></li>' +
           ' <li ng-click="logout()">Logout</li>' +
        '</ul>' + '</div>';
        $compile(id)($scope);
```

I am struggling in finding out what should be done in order to **close** the **drop down** when user clicks elsewhere in page ?

This is SPA so i have one html page. In the rest i am using **ui-routing** to dynamically append contents.

May i get some help to fix this?

Any help would be appreciated !

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this

```
   $document.click((e) => {
    let element = angular.element('.enterElementClassName')
     if (!element.is(e.target) && element.has(e.target).length === 0)      {
        // close popup condition
    }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you fahad. May i know what is enterElementClassName in the above code? Also should i write above code in app.js?

Comment: great ('#ProfileDropdown')

Comment: Thank you fahad. Now whenever i click anywhere in page event is firing. May i know how can close above dropodwn?

Comment: Remove that class which you add on click of drop-down.

Comment: i tried      angular.element(document.querySelector("#ProfileDropdown")).removeClass("data-drop-down"); and this is not working.

Comment: Can you give me running example on jsFiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150053/discussion-between-fahad-and-niranjan-godbole).

Answer (score 0):

For doing it in angular, [Remove/Add Class in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460369/adding-and-removing-classes-in-angularjs-using-ng-click)
You can use **$scope.class** method to do remove the class of **Dropdown** to **hide/remove** it from Web Page.

OR

In **Javascript/JQuery**

There can be several solutions for closing drop-down,
On basis of some assumptions:
Assume you have some class of the element which describes dropdown, for Ex:

```
var id = document.getElementById('ProfileDropdown');
        id.innerHTML = $scope.ProfileDropdown = '  <div data-drop-down class="dropdown_menu">' + ' <ul>' +
                '<li ><a ui-sref="Dashboard.Userprofile">User Profile</a></li>' +
            '<li><a ui-sref="Dashboard.changepassword">Change Password</a></li>' +
              '<li><a ui-sref="Dashboard.LeaseListings">Lease Request</a></li>' +
                 '<li><a ui-sref="#">Service Request</a></li>' +
                   '<li><a ui-sref="Dashboard.NewServiceRequest">New Service Request</a></li>' +
           ' <li ng-click="logout()">Logout</li>' +
        '</ul>' + '</div>';
        $compile(id)($scope);
```

Now To close the **dropdown** you can fire an **Event targeting the main** **wrapper** of your HTML Markup and remove the class which got appended in the **div**.
To **remove/close** the **element/class** is different context and out of scope from this question, For that you can refer [This Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463486/jquery-drop-down-menu-closing-by-clicking-outside)

Hope that helps,

Thanks & Regards

Shohil Sethia

Comment: Thank you Shohil. I am looking for pure angular code.

Comment: Hi @NiranjanGodbole
Check the answer now, 
Have updated it for angular, You can refer the given link and you can remove class in angular itself and also add any css to it like **fadeOut** or others etc.

Hope it helps, 
Regards